I'm trying to use spine in pixi.js project but it comes with unexpected problem
Hello I'm trying to use Spine for my small pixi.js application.
So the main problem here in my project is that, whenever I'm trying to initialize spine in some file it only gives me one error 
I'm also sharing these chunks of codes that I'm using for example: loading assets,calling spine and etc.
ALSO VERSIONS THAT I'M USING
Pixi.js v7.3.2 | pixi-spine v4.0.4 | And exported spine is "spine": "3.8.75" version
This is method to get spine:
getSpine(key: string, bundle: string = BundlesEnum.GAME_ICONS): any {
    return this.loaded[bundle][key];
  }

Class where I'm trying to call this loaded Spine:
import { Container } from "pixi.js";
import { RESOURCES } from "../global/global.config";
import { Spine } from "pixi-spine";

export default class SpineView extends Container {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.draw();
  }

  draw() {
    // This takes spineBoy resource from loaded resources
    const resource = RESOURCES.getSpine("spineboy");
    console.log(resource);

    // and here it is getting assigned to Spine
    const spine = new Spine(resource);
    this.addChild(spine);

    // This should work right? NO IT DOESNT
  }
}

And also here is the method which I'm using for loading resources (btw this method works)
private async loadAssets(bundles: string[] = []): Promise<void> {
    const manifest = this.unloadedResources;

    const bundlesToLoad =
      bundles.length == 0
        ? manifest.bundles?.map((bundle: any) => bundle.name)
        : bundles;

    await Assets.init({ manifest });

    return Assets.loadBundle(bundlesToLoad);
  }

I've checked everything and as I can see it logs out this object which is spineData as I can see
I checked everything naming loading assets and etc, everything but nothing gives me proper answer of what might be the problem, even the almighty chatgpt can't help me.
It logs out error which i mentioned in top bar... so anyone who knows something about this please help if u need any more info just tell me and I can add to it.
Thank you in advance!

As per the pixijs/spine documentation you need to add import 'pixi-spine' on starting of the class SpineView.
The imports in your class should look like:
import 'pixi-spine' // Do this once at the very start of your code. This registers the loader!
import { Container } from "pixi.js";
import { RESOURCES } from "../global/global.config";
import { Spine } from "pixi-spine";

